# AppEngine Dynamic WebProject - Ear libraries not copied to War Project Web-INF/lib folder

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp, google-app-engine

I have a Ear Project which includes two Appengine Dynamic Web Project and one shared java project (which has common classes).

I have added shared java project to EarContent Folder through Deployment assembly settings in EAR Project and i can see the java project jar file in published folder under EarContent folder.

Now i wanted to use the Ear library in Dynamic Web Project, so i have added this library in MANIFEST.MF setting for both the project and at compile time i can access the class from shared project too.

The problem is when i publish it, i couldn't able to find the java project jar in Both Web Project, i have tried almost every settings but nothing was helpful.

Am using Eclipse Mars, AppEngine SDK version 1.9.10,

Does any one tried this, is there any possible solution for my problem. any thoughts or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see this: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10652

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Google Plugin for Eclipse doesn't recognize anything in EarContent/lib (or whatever your EAR library path is) regardless of settings when packaging the WAR files for each Dynamic Web Project. The JARs need to be physically present in WEB-INF/lib for each Dynamic Web Project in order for the modules to deploy properly.

I would recommend opening a feature request in the official issue tracker here:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues